# How can I get the option to ask if an RV camper can move in?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

I currently have 9 villagers in my town, and I am planning to build a campsite (the public works project) very soon. From my understanding, if you have 9 villagers then the camper from the campsite you've built has a chance of moving in your town. Is this the same for the RV camper, the one next to Harvey? Someone told me that they can kick an existing villager out and take their place. Do I need an amiibo card for this? Because I don't have an amiibo card. I tried talking to an RV camper a bunch of times but it doesn't seem like there would be an option for him to move in. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The campsite lets villagers visit your town though they stay in the camp store tent. You know when a villager is there when a tent is there. If you talk to them they might move in or they might move in if you win a mini game. You do not need anything for villagers to visit the campsite.